# Add two tabs group in same page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to add two tabs group in same page ,but it works as one tab ,If i select first tab from tab group one it inactive  the selected tab in other group,How anyone help me to fix that?

tab group one

```
 <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <!-- <span class="pull-right small text-muted">1406 
        Elements</span> -->
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 1}"><a ng-click="tab = 1"
                ng-init="tab = 1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Program Summary</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 2}"><a ng-click="tab = 2"><i
                    class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Risk Summary</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 3}"><a ng-click="tab = 3"><i
                    class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Others</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab == 1">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab == 2">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab == 3">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

tab group two

```
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <!-- <span class="pull-right small text-muted">1406 Elements</span> -->
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 11}"><a ng-click="tab = 11"
                ng-init="tab = 11"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Program Summary</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 22}"><a ng-click="tab =22"><i
                    class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Risk Summary</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : tab == 33}"><a ng-click="tab =33"><i
                    class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Others</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab-11" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab == 11">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-22" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab ==22">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-33" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="tab ==33">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    TAB3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Suggest you get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui bootstrap which also has no jQuery dependency